# Jest error -- Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the configuration of a service inside a component in React and I am having problems with jest and testing-library, the app is working but the test is blocking.

```
  import { appSetupConfig } from '.../myapp'
  import theConfig from '.../config'

  useEffect(() => {
    const allowAppInstance = appSetupConfig();

    allowAppInstance.get(theConfig).then((value) => {
       if (value.something) {
           Do Something;
       } 
    ...the rest of code

  }, []);
```

This theConfig is an external file containing an object.
This is the error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

  37 |     const allowAppInstance = appSetupConfig();
  38 | 
> 39 |     allowAppInstance.get(theConfig).then((value) => {
```

**Is there any way to mock this get in jest's setup.js?**
I don’t necessarily need to test this item yet, but I can’t proceed without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. So it would seem that you have called `jest.mock('.../myapp')` or similar at some point. In the mock object that Jest creates for the module, every mock function returns `undefined`. You need to mock a return value on `appSetupConfig` that is itself a mock object with the method(s) you need like `get`. Then `get` in turn needs to return a mock promise, and so on as deeply as needed. In your setup file, this would look like:

```js
import { appSetupConfig } from '.../myapp'
...
jest.mock('.../myapp');
appSetupConfig.mockReturnValue({
  get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ something: jest.fn() }),
});
```

Your `.then` block will then be called in the test(s) with `value` set to `undefined`, but you can mock a different resolved value or a rejection of the promise for particular tests.

Comment: Thank you very much! But now I got the same error in value.something. This jest is so hard =(

Comment: Indeed, you'll have to keep mocking return values within return values until you cover everything you access from the module(s) you're testing. If that gets to be tangled, you can centralize it in a [module factory](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) for the entire `myapp` mock.

Comment: Do i need to do the same thing you did with .get? Can you show me an example? Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Yep, it looks the same all the way down. I edited my answer to show `get`'s mock resolved value be an object with a mock function `something`.